# How to find the minimum value of potential in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

In MIT problem sets I followed a solution of an exercise which focuses on odd-parity energy eigenstates in finite square well.

The point of problem is how to know or find the minimal value of potential to conclude the sign of $E$?

Since we know $E\ge V_\mathrm{min}$, in the region $|x|>L$,  $V(x)=0$ then the Schrödinger equation becomes:

$$\psi''(x) = \frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2} \psi (x)$$
How do we know $E<0$? isn't $V=0$ here then $E$ must $>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a situation where there's a negative potential $V_{{\rm min}}$ inside the well, maybe from $-L<x<L$, and $V=0$ elsewhere. You have two scenarios possible: bound states, and free states. A free state is one in which the particle's energy is greater than the asymptotic limit of the potential, so that there are no classically forbidden regions (since $V=0$ for $|x|\to \infty$, this just means that E>0 gives you free (unbound) states, while E<0 give you bound states).

For an unbound state ($E>0$), the Schrödinger equation simplifies to

$$\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)=-\dfrac{2m\epsilon}{\hbar^2}\psi(x),$$

where $\epsilon$ is the "height" of your energy above the potential "floor" at that point ($\epsilon=E-V_{{\rm min}}$ inside, $\epsilon=E$ outside). This has solutions that are sinusoidal

$$\psi(x)=Ae^{\frac{i\sqrt{2m\epsilon}}{\hbar}x}+Be^{-\frac{i\sqrt{2m\epsilon}}{\hbar}x}.$$

For bound states, the region inside the well stays the same. However, outside the well, you're in the classically forbidden region (you don't have enough energy to be admitted there, right?). Here, $E-V_{{\rm min}}<0$, and your solution looks like a decaying exponential. You get sinusoidal solutions within the well, and decaying exponentials outside of it.